# rsyslog fromhost-ip using external lookup table

Tags: rsyslog, rhel7

Working on a RHEL 7 host, configuring rsyslog to collect udp/tcp events from a wide range of devices (routers, switches, appliances, etc.) from several hundred IP's. Using the config below to start with.

**The question**: Is there a way in rsyslog to call an external table of IP addresses used by "fromhost-ip" so that I don't have to have dozens or more lines with each individual IP listed, but instead update the list instead?  Since the IP's are not in the same range (many not even in the same CIDR block) I cannot use "startswith" and not aware that rsyslog recognizes CIDR notation or subnet mask.

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
#
# Provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514
#
$template networking,"/var/log/splunk/networking/%FROMHOST-IP%/%FROMHOST-  IP%_%$now%.log"
$template firewall,"/var/log/splunk/firewall/%FROMHOST-IP%/%FROMHOST-IP%_%$now%.log"
$template security,"/var/log/splunk/security/%FROMHOST-IP%/%FROMHOST-IP%_%$now%.log"
$template infrastructure,"/var/log/splunk/infrastructure/%FROMHOST-IP%/%FROMHOST-IP%_%$now%.log"
$template linux,"/var/log/splunk/linux/%FROMHOST-IP%/%FROMHOST-IP%_%$now%.log"
$template uncategorized,"/var/log/splunk/uncategorized/%FROMHOST-IP%/%FROMHOST-IP%_%$now%.log"
#
if $msg contains "%ASA-" then ?firewall
if $fromhost-ip == [ "172.31.4.3","172.31.4.2" ] then ?firewall
& ~

if $fromhost-ip == [ '172.31.4.211', '172.31.4.212', '172.31.4.213' ] then ?networking
& ~

if $fromhost-ip == [ '172.31.4.200','172.31.4.201','172.31.4.203' ] then ?security
& ~

if $fromhost-ip == [ '172.31.4.241','172.31.4.242','172.31.4.243' ] then ?infrastructure
& ~

if $fromhost-ip == [ '172.31.4.250','172.31.4.251','172.31.4.253' ] then ?linux
& ~

if $fromhost-ip != '127.0.0.1' then  ?uncategorized
& ~
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of rsyslog you have in Rhel7, nor when this feature became available, but you might be able to use RainerScript [tables](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/lookup_tables.html).

You have to provide a file, say `mytable.json` holding a json formatted table with the needed keys and values, for example:

```
{ "version" : 1,
  "nomatch" : "uncategorized",
  "type"    : "string",
  "table" : [
    {"index" : "172.31.4.211", "value" : "networking" },
    {"index" : "127.0.0.1",    "value" : "linux" },
  ]}
```

Obviously, it would be best to generate this with a small awk script from a more editable list of addresses and categories.

You load this table in the config file using `lookup_table()`. Then simply provide a single generic template using a variable `$.myclass` instead of all the multitude of categories, and set that variable by a `lookup()` from the table.
For example,

```
lookup_table(name="myipmap" file="mytable.json" reloadOnHUP="on")
$template all,"/var/log/splunk/%$.myclass%/%FROMHOST-IP%/%FROMHOST-IP%_%$now%.log"
set $.myclass = lookup("myipmap", $fromhost-ip);
action(type="omfile" dynaFile="all")
```